# Boolean Algebra Proof for a + a = a and (a * b)' = a' + b'

Tags: boolean-algebra

Prove, for any element $a$ in a boolean algebra expression, that $a + a = a$. Prove also, for any two elements, $a$ and $b$, of a boolean algebra expression, that $(a * b)' = a' + b'$.

Comment: Whats $+$? Etc, juse mathjax.

Comment: I suppose $+$ stands for $\lor$, $\cdot$ for $\land$

Comment: I proved it. That's all you wanted, right? (Please ask, instead of commanding, and use proper formatting.)

Answer (score 1):

Idempotent law a  + a = a

Proof:  x  + x

= (x  + x) • 1

=  (x  +  x)  •  (x  + x')

=  x + (x  • x')

=  x + 0 =  x

And for other prove see de-morgan's law.

Answer (score 0):

I can't prove DeMorgan's Law (the second equation you gave) because, quite frankly, I don't know how, but I can prove your first expression. I will be using symbols from boolean algebra, not formal logic.

In boolean algebra addition represents or ($\lor$), multiplication represents and ($\land$), and a bar ($\bar{}$) over an element represents a negation ($\neg$).

### Proof of $x + x = x$

\begin{align}
x + x &= x && \text{Original Equation}\\
x + x &= x + 0 && \text{Identity Law}\\
x + x &= x + x\bar{x} && \text{Zero Property}\\
x + x &= (x + x)(x + \bar{x}) && \text{Distributive Law}\\
x + x &= (x + x) * 1 && \text{Unit Property}\\
x + x &= x + x && \text{Identity Law}\\
\end{align}

---

### Laws and Properties Used

#### Identity Law:

$$
x + 0 = x
$$
$$
x * 1 = x
$$

#### Distributive Law

$$
x + yz = (x + y)(x + z)
$$
$$
x(y + z) = xy + xz
$$

#### Zero Property

$$
x\bar{x} = 0
$$

#### Unit Property

$$
x + \bar{x} = 1
$$

Comment: I'll ask one of my discrete mathematics professors soon how to prove DeMorgan's Law. If I'm able to understand it myself, I will edit this answer and add the proof and any laws/properties used in addition to the ones that I used for the first proof.

Answer (score -1):

from right side

=a

=a+0

=a+(a.a')

=(a+a).(a+a')

=(a+a).1

=a+a